# Cosmosdb mongo create index over a big collection - risks

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection with 2 million records and I want to add a single field index over it if possible without downtime.

My questions are:
Is it possible/desired to backup the collection?
Creating the index with azure portal runs it over background without any service downtime?
Any other special careful I should be aware of?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As of Aug 2020, there is no impact in changing the indexing. You can do so without any impact to the existing reads and writes. The RU/s used for the indexing will be from what is available.
[No downtime indexing updates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/no-downtime-indexing-updates-in-azure-cosmos-db/)
So you can safely change the indexing at any time.

Azure is already automatically taking backups of your containers [Cosmos auto backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/online-backup-and-restore#:%7E:text=Azure%20Cosmos%20DB%20automatically%20takes,separately%20in%20a%20storage%20service.) but I really don't see any need to do this. Indexing doesn't impact the data in anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There is no downtime required for updating the indexes in cosmos db. There is no impact to read/write availability during any index transformations. The index transformation uses your provisioned RUs but at a lower priority than your CRUD operations or queries.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#modifying-the-indexing-policy